# why does subtraction overflow with static_cast?

Tags: c++, static-cast, size-type

I understand that `s1.size() - s2.size()` underflows when `s2` is bigger because it's subtraction of `unsigned`.
Why casting one them to `int` doesn't result in integer subtraction?
Why casting the whole thing gives me the correct result? I expected it to evaluate what is inside parentheses, then underflow which would give a big number and then the cast to `int` would not make difference. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
    return (static_cast<int>(s1.size()) - s2.size() < 0) ? true : false; // underflows
    //return (static_cast<int>(s1.size() - s2.size()) < 0) ? true : false; // this works

}
int main() { 
    string s, t;
    getline(cin, s);
    getline(cin, t);
    cout << "s: " << s << endl;
    cout << "t: " << t << endl;
    cout << "printing shorter string of the two..." << endl;
    cout << ((isShorter(s, t)) ? s : t) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the rule that says `signed + unsigned = unsigned`.

Comment: Also note that you can do the same thing without subtraction and casting at all.  `return ((s1.size() < s2.size()) ? true : false);`

Comment: @NathanOliver or just `return s1.size() < s2.size();`

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh yeah.  Silly me :-)

Comment: @nwp makes sense, my bad. What about the cast that takes the subtraction inside? Why doesn't it work as i described?

Comment: @power_output because for it to work you need to `static_cast` both values

Comment: How does the static_cast exactly work? I give it the subtraction inside, but if it does that subtraction it will underflow, that underflow will be a big number, casting that to integer doesn't help. The cast doesn't work like this?

Comment: You need to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
static_cast<int>(s1.size()) - s2.size()
```

You convert `s1.size()` to a `int` and then when you subtract `s2.size()` from it that `int` is promoted to the same type as `s2.size()` and then it is subtracted.  This means you still have unsigned integer subtraction and since that can't ever be negative it will wrap around to a larger number.  It is no different from doing `s1.size() - s2.size()`.

You have the same thing with

```
static_cast<int>(s1.size() - s2.size())
```

With the added bonus of possible signed integer overflow which is undefined behavior.  You are still doing unsigned integer subtraction so if `s1` is smaller than `s2` than you wrap around to a large number.

What you need to do is convert both `s1.size()` and `s2.size()` to a signed integer type to get singed integer subtraction.  That could look like

```
static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(s1.size())  - static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(s2.size())
```

And now you will actually get a negative number if `s1.size()` is less than `s2.size()`.

---

It should be noted that all of this can be avoided by using less than operator.  Your function can be rewritten to be

```
bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

which, IMHO, is much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Casting "one of them" to `int` leaves you with arithmetic operation that mixes `string::size_type` and `int`. In this mix the unsigned type has the same rank as `int` or higher, which means that the unsigned type still "wins": your `int` is implicitly converted back to `string::size_type` and the calculations are performed in the domain of `string::size_type`. Your conversion to `int` is effectively ignored.

Meanwhile, casting the result to `int` means that you are attempting to convert a value that does not fit into `int`'s range. The behavior in such cases is implementation defined. In real-life 2's-complement implementations it is not unusual to see a simple truncation of the representation, which produces the "correct" result. This is not a good approach though.

If you want to perform this subtraction as a signed one, you have to convert *both* operands to signed types, making sure that the target signed type can represent both values.

(Theoretically, you can get away with converting just one operand to signed type, but for that you'd need to choose a type that can represent the entire range of `string::size_type`.)